# My question is, is this a possible/valid way to add a "hidden" outlet for outside IP camera?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

So I basically wanted to do what the OP wanted to do [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/)...

However, I wasn't sure if one needed to actually cut thru the siding and add a new gang box + receptacle/outlet in order to plug in the IPcam's wallwart power adapter... or if my wiring/connections are right... I think they are...

So I did this:

[image: hack]

I spliced together the cables coming from the switch, the exterior lamp's cables (not pictured), and the cables that feed the outlet. I put those twisting plastic wire nuts on all connections, and put the lamp back on.
I wanted to avoid drilling/cutting on the hardiplank siding cuz it's a pain (super hard) and kinda want the power adapter to be hidden as it's def not for outdoor use...

My question is, is this a possible/valid way to do it? I nailed the outlet to a stud on the right (without a plastic gangbox) and just pulled the 5V DC cable to thru a small opening on the lamp's housing/base.

Also could an outlet being hidden like that be a code violation? fire hazard? Where can find out about whether this is ok code-wise in my area? I'm in Metro-Atlanta, GA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally "not valid" (under NEC rules) since you are combining low voltage and high voltage in a box without a barrier separating them. That is, it's a clear code violation.

> I nailed the outlet to a stud on the right (**without a plastic gangbox**)

That sounds rather like an **additional** code violation.

48V POE (af/at) or 24V passive POE (Power Over Ethernet) are generally much better ways to handle powering cameras, since there is no need to make horrible kludges to get a power adapter anywhere near the camera.

Comment: Got it, yeah I had a feeling my hack was not even close to kosher... Where can I read up on these codes?

Comment: NFPA now gives free access to the [National Electrical Code](http://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards?mode=code&code=70), provided you create an account and agree to the terms of use.  Other than that, you'd have to buy, rent, or borrow a copy.

Comment: @Tester101 thanks, I'll definitely look into that